# Next.js 14 Unhandled Runtime Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using nextJS14

⨯ node_modules\next-auth\react\index.js (113:10) @ useSession
⨯ Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components
at Home (./app/page.tsx:18:90)
at stringify ()
digest: "38333500"
null

```
//Page.tsx

import Documents from "@/components/Documents";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Hero from "@/components/Hero";
import Login from "@/components/Login";
import { useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession({ required: true });
  if (!session) return <Login />;

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Hero />
      <Documents />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//Layout.tsx

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Google Docs",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are encountering has to do with the fact that you are trying to access some context (in this case your session) inside a [server component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) where context is not available. I recommend you create a [client component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components) that checks this for you:

```
"use client"; // this makes this component a client component

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

export default function AuthGuard({ children }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const router = useRouter();
  const session = useSession({ required: true });
  
  // checks the session each time it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session) router.replace("/login");
  }, [session]);

  return <>{children}</>;
}

export type { Props as AuthGuardProps };
```

Inside your layout you can then simply import this component and wrap your content with it, but don't worry: Wrapping a server component with a client component does not cause the whole application to be rendered on the client.

```
import AuthGuard from "@/components/AuthGuard";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <SessionProvider>
          <AuthGuard>{children}</AuthGuard>
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: now i have this error " Error: [next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />" same sessionProvider error is also there when  i am making page.tsx client side "use client"

Comment: @Abhishek Have you even read the documentation of your authentication framework? You need to import the `SessionProvider` component and wrap your application with it. I updated the example. By the way, if you find this answer useful; Consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: still not working tried every thing